# Permissions deleting files on persistent host storage: Can docker run as user not root?

Tags: docker, permissions

I've setup a docker container that mounts a volume that is persistent on the host machine:

```
docker volume create --name work type=none --opt device=/home/username --opt o=bind
docker container run -it --rm --mount source=work,target=/work
```

I run the container and do stuff, so let's say:

```
echo "Hello world" > testfile.txt
```

When I try to delete whatever files (e.g. testfile.txt) the container writes to /work (which maps to /home/username on the host) from a host terminal, I am getting permissions error because it is written and owned by root.

Is there a way to setup Docker to run as the current user that I am logged on to, so this permissions issue doesn't arise? Also, is there a reason it runs as root (will other functionality break if I can somehow run as a user)? I know I can always chown by way through, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a non root user to your container and set that as default:

```
RUN useradd -m myuser
USER myuser # every command below is executed by myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
```

Use `USER root` to switch to `root` user again. ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user))

To get permission to delete the files on the host the host user and the container user need to have the same user id.

To check the user ids you can use `id -u <username>`. If the ids don't match use the option `-u <userid>` to create your user:

```
RUN useradd -m -u <userid> <username>
```

See [useradd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/useradd.8.html) for more information.